# Automatic date function not working properly

Tags: google-sheets

I made a budget spreadsheet for myself, and while I need to pretty it up a bit (because why not), everything works beautifully a full week later except one function (which seems to work in most cases.

Column D of the page 'Bills' contains the numerical day of the month that a bill is paid on. Column C of the same page has this function:

> =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D1)), IF(OR(AND('Current Week'!B$2 <= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), D1), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),
>   MONTH(TODAY()), D1) <= 'Current Week'!D$2), AND('Current Week'!D$2 <=
>   DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), D1),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),
>   MONTH(TODAY()), D1) <= EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),
>   MONTH(TODAY()), D1), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) + 1, D1)), )

Which checks for that day being inside the current week and not before the end of the month, and turns it into the date that that bill would fall on. It works fine most of the time, including last week for the entire week, but this week, with the first of my pay-week being Tuesday, July 31 2018, it seems to have gone a little pear shaped and gone ahead and placed it into the next month (in this case, August 31) despite the 31st of July being part of this pay-week.

I feel like I've either AND-ed something incorrectly or else referenced a cell incorrectly, but I'll be damned if I can figure out where. Help!

Spreadsheet for reference (Page 'Bills' column D is the problem child. The lines "Paycheck 1" and "Example Bill showcase the problem)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1etOpyc_HkRjMTssWZyNX0ru-0RVaHO-NoJ1HljlzyAE/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Ok so I've realized what's happening but still not sure what to do about it. It's setting the month of the date to the month of the current date.

Comment: That's a seriously complex formula.  Have you tried splitting it out into components and making sure they all output as expected individually?  That may be the easiest way to troubleshoot.

Comment: i actually built it in that fashion. and it does 'what it's supposed to', but there's a factor that i never considered, and i'm having trouble finding what to do to compensate. when the date is part of the current week but (should be) part of last month (e.g. week starts before end of month but finishes after that), it's not picking that up. and i'm not sure what to do with it :/

Comment: it's also not as bad as it looks, just lots of date conversions in it :P